# Remove digits from pandas df column index

Tags: pandas, python-3.6

Can someone please point me towards the best way to remove the numbers from this df.columns.
The df:

```
            1. open 2. high 3. low     4. close 5. volume
date                    
2000-01-03  1469.25 1478.00 1438.3600   1455.22 9.318000e+08
2000-01-04  1455.22 1455.22 1397.4301   1399.42 1.009000e+09
```

desired output:

```
            open    high    low       close     volume
date                    
2000-01-03  1469.25 1478.00 1438.3600 1455.22   9.318000e+08
2000-01-04  1455.22 1455.22 1397.4301 1399.42   1.009000e+09
```

`.split('.')[1].strip()` works but doesn't seem so elegant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Index.str.extract` to extract the words out:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z]+)', expand=False)
```

Comment: this does the opposite of what i want actually. removes the words.

Comment: @steff you probably used a capital "W" instead of a small "w".

Comment: using lower case 'w'. The output shows the numbers as column names instead of the words

Comment: @steff I relish the bug was with \w indeed which also captures digits. I've changed the pattern to explicitly match letters only, so this should work now. Take another look and mark the answer if it helped. Thanks.

Comment: that works indeed. Thanks so much coldspeed. Sorry about late reply.